# Theoretical efficiency of a laser

Tags: thermodynamics, laser, bosons, carnot-cycle

A laser produces a coherent, collimated light beam. This is like a less-disordered version of the light from say a light bulb. When I learned about heat pumps in thermodynamics class, I found that we have a reasonable understanding of [the theoretical efficiency of a device like an air conditioner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_efficiency), which lowers the disorder of a system (the inside air) by removing energy from it. But I haven't seen anyone discuss the efficiency of lasers in terms of entropy reduction. Is it theoretically just as efficient to produce a coherent, collimated light beam, as a laser does, as it is to send blackbody photons randomly in all directions like a light bulb does?

Or can we say that there is some energy cost to making the output of a laser so ordered? If so, what is it? Does it depend on temperature? Wavelength? Aperture size?

Here are some other questions of a similar nature: Network Engineering: [What is pump conversion efficiency](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/55464/49445). Physics SE: [Why are lasers inefficient?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12965/why-are-lasers-inefficient), [Laser power consumption vs power output](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/159851/laser-power-consumption-vs-power-output/160124). Engineering SE: [What is laser efficiency?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38410/laser-efficiency-what-is-this-term). These seem to approach the question from more of an engineering standpoint, which would ask about the observed efficiency of a particular laser design; rather than a physics standpoint, asking as I do about the theoretical maximum efficiency of any design producing coherent collimated light of a certain geometry, power, and wavelength.